# Passing props to child component Cyclejs

Tags: cyclejs

I m studying CycleJs and I m looking for a proper way to handle passing props to child component.

Actually, I m having the following stuff :

```
import {div, input} from '@cycle/dom'


export function App(sources) {
    const inputOnChange$ = sources.DOM.select('input').events('input')
    const streamofResult = inputOnChange$
        .map(e => e.target.value)
        .startWith('')
        .map(defaultInput => {
            const title = Title({value: defaultInput})
            return div([
                title,
                input({attrs: {type: 'text'}})
            ])
        })
    const sinks = {DOM: streamofResult}
    return sinks
}


export function Title(sources) {
    return div(sources.value)
}
```

It simply allows to make some inputs, and to display it in a child component called Title.

I think I should use a stream to handle passing props to my child.

But I don't understand why it would be a better solution in this simple to use a stream instead of a primitive ?

There is something that I probably have not understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't misunderstood anything. There is no right answer. If you know for a fact you'll never want to change the `props` after initialization then you could pass the `props` as a primitive, but the more common convention is to send a `props$` since it's not much costlier to do something like `O.of(x)` vs `x` (assuming RxJS) and using streams everywhere is consistent with the philosophy of the framework.  Additionally, there are occasions when you'll want to change the properties dynamically after component initialization, where a stream is appropriate.

Keeping a consistent `props` or `props$` convention for all your components can make reading the code easier since you won't have to think, "Does this component use a primitive or a stream for props...?"